# Selenium & C# | How can I click a button in a table?

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

Below is a section of HTML I'm having trouble with.

What I'm attempting to do: I'm currently using selenium chrome driver to go through the process of creating a ticket on a website. At a certain page, I have to select a tab in order to check a few checkboxes (see below). However, they all have the same ID. How can I select (say the 2nd TOP_TAB & TOP_BUTTON) using selenium chrome driver in C# and click the element.

```
<input type="hidden" name="tabsize" value="5">

<td id="TOP_TAB" width="10" class="leftRightBorder" style="width: 5px;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('0','0');" align="center" nowrap=""><img src="images/left-cor.gif" width="5" height="18" border="0"></td>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 10px; background-color: rgb(181, 200, 217); border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(181, 200, 217); font-weight: normal;"
                    onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('0','0');" align="center" class="drop" nowrap="" bgcolor="#B5C8D9" width="88">Addendum 02</td>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('0','0');" align="center" nowrap=""><img src="images/right-cor.gif" width="5" height="18" border="0"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>

<td id="TOP_TAB" width="10" class="leftRightBorder" style="width: 5px;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('1','1');" align="center" nowrap=""><img src="images/left-cor-light.gif" width="5" height="18" border="0"></td>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 10px; background-color: rgb(217, 223, 239); border-bottom: 0px solid rgb(217, 223, 239); font-weight: bold;"
                    onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('1','1');" align="center" class="drop" nowrap="" bgcolor="#B5C8D9" width="88">Addendum 01</td>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('1','1');" align="center" nowrap=""><img src="images/right-cor-light.gif" width="5" height="18" border="0"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>

<td id="TOP_TAB" width="10" class="leftRightBorder" style="width: 5px;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('2','2');" align="center" nowrap=""><img src="images/left-cor.gif" width="5" height="18" border="0"></td>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 10px; background-color: rgb(181, 200, 217); border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(181, 200, 217); font-weight: normal;"
                    onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('2','2');" align="center" class="drop" nowrap="" bgcolor="#B5C8D9" width="88">Default Job</td>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('2','2');" align="center" nowrap=""><img src="images/right-cor.gif" width="5" height="18" border="0"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>

<td id="TOP_TAB" width="10" class="leftRightBorder" style="width: 5px;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('3','3');" align="center" nowrap=""><img src="images/left-cor.gif" width="5" height="18" border="0"></td>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 10px; background-color: rgb(181, 200, 217); border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(181, 200, 217); font-weight: normal;"
                    onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('3','3');" align="center" class="drop" nowrap="" bgcolor="#B5C8D9" width="88">Default Job</td>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('3','3');" align="center" nowrap=""><img src="images/right-cor.gif" width="5" height="18" border="0"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>

<td id="TOP_TAB" width="10" class="leftRightBorder" style="width: 5px;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('4','4');" align="center" nowrap=""><img src="images/left-cor.gif" width="5" height="18" border="0"></td>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 10px; background-color: rgb(181, 200, 217); border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(181, 200, 217); font-weight: normal;"
                    onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('4','4');" align="center" class="drop" nowrap="" bgcolor="#B5C8D9" width="88">Default Job</td>
                <td id="TOP_BUTTON" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="fun_HideShowBlock('4','4');" align="center" nowrap=""><img src="images/right-cor.gif" width="5" height="18" border="0"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

Comment: I'll do XPath to select all the TOP_TAB elements( loop until its the one I need) and then a 2nd XPath to look for all the TOP_BUTTON (iterate and select the index I need)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know it'll always be the second tab you can do this (and same idea for the button).

```
driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("descendant::td[@id = 'TOP_TAB']"))[1];
```

if you don't know that it will be the second one but know you need the one with Addendum 01 in it, you can do this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("descendant::td[text() = 'Addendum 01']/ancestor::td[@id = 'TOP_TAB']"));
```

the second way gets you the item you want and then walks back up to the tab you want.

Comment: This first one worked perfectly. Thanks you for this.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it worked so others will know it's correct :)